# GWT: an external page is opening ONLY when cookie is disabled

Tags: google-sites

I have created a website with the Google website. One of my pages is opening an external web page, not Google web page. I used the iframe that the Google site offers. The problem is it requires the cookie enabled. I need to open the external page weather the cookie enabled or disabled.

My site is http://www.zenandyoga.com/
The second tab on the menu, schedule is the page. The below page is opening when the menu Schedule is opened. 
https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/home.asp?studioid=10273

As I said if the cookie is disabled, the page is opening.

Any idea what could be the reason

thanks

Comment: I didn't understand what does it have to do with GWT.

Comment: @GilbertoTorrezan Nothing. Mis-tagging. (I'd actually even say it's probably not on the appropriate stackexchange site: SO is for programmers, Google Sites is hardly about _programming_)